# How to implement jScroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, jscrollpane

Im a beginner in JS & jQuery so please bear with me.

Im trying to create a dynamic list `<ul>` using JS and finally its working. Now i need to implement the infinite scrolling concept in my list, using [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/) plugin.

So i researched a lot about jScroll, but i cant find any tutorial i needed. Most of the tutorials using `PHP` language pretty much, while in my case i have done my server (`PHP`) code using simple `SELECT` query with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` on it and returning a `json`.

This is my jQuery/AJAX code that create the dynamic list from database, **its already working** :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/jwmws/index.php/jwm/search/msmall/"+keyword, //This is the current doc
    type: "GET",
    error : function(jq, st, err) {
        alert(st + " : " + err);
    },
    success: function(result){
        //generate search result
        //float:left untuk hack design
        $('#search').append('<p style="float:left;">Search for : ' + keyword + '</p>'
            + '<br/>'
            + '<p>Found ' + result.length + ' results</p>');

        if(result.length == 0)
        {
            //temp
            alert("not found");
        }
        else{
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                //generate <li>
                $('#list').append('<li class="box"><img class="picture" src="images/HotPromo/tagPhoto1.png"/><p class="name"><b>Name</b></p><p class="address">Address</p></li>');
            }

            var i=0;
            $(".box").each(function(){
                var name, address, picture = "";
                if(i < result.length)
                {
                    name = result[i].name;
                    address = result[i].address;
                    picture = result[i].boxpicture;
                }

                $(this).find(".name").html(name);
                $(this).find(".address").html(address);
                $(this).find(".picture").attr("src", picture);
                i++;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Because my dynamic list is already working, now i just need to implement the jScroll. However, i dont understand its code, like :

```
$('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: 'li'
});
```

How to implement this in my case? I just append `<li>` in my jQUery/AJAX so how about the `nextSelector`?

Any help is appreciated, please just ask if you have some question.

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: recall function in ajax success

Comment: @Hushme sorry but what do you mean by recall?Thanks :D

Comment: call $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({...again in success function

Comment: @Hushme what about the nextSelector?what should i add?Thanks :D

Comment: it should be the same

Answer (score 7):

You hava every thing prety much set just needed to call jscroll at proper time.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/jwmws/index.php/jwm/search/msmall/"+keyword, //This is the current doc
        type: "GET",
        error : function(jq, st, err) {
            alert(st + " : " + err);
        },
        success: function(result){
            //generate search result
            //float:left untuk hack design
            $('#search').append('<p style="float:left;">Search for : ' + keyword + '</p>'
                            + '<br/>' 
                            + '<p>Found ' + result.length + ' results</p>');

            if(result.length == 0)
            {
                //temp
                alert("not found");
            }
            else{
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                {
                    //generate <li>
                    $('#list').append('<li class="box"><img class="picture" src="images/HotPromo/tagPhoto1.png"/><p class="name"><b>Name</b></p><p class="address">Address</p></li>');
                }
                //After generation of <li> put a next link
                $('#list').append('<a href="#" class="jscroll-next">NEXT</a>');
                //call to jscroller to be triggered
                jscroller();
                var i=0;
                $(".box").each(function(){
                    var name, address, picture = "";
                    if(i < result.length)
                    {
                        name = result[i].name;
                        address = result[i].address;
                        picture = result[i].boxpicture;
                    }

                    $(this).find(".name").html(name);
                    $(this).find(".address").html(address);
                    $(this).find(".picture").attr("src", picture);
                    i++;
                });
            }
        }
        });

//The function to be called when <li> are rendered.
function jscroller(){
 $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
     loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
     padding: 20,
     nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
     contentSelector: 'li'
 });
}
```

Comment: Hello, i need to load 50 rows each time untill it finish.so how i can give counter to jscroll.